# Android GCM not received in KITKAT

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Hello I am new in android. I have created an android app with GCM push notification. I created this app using android studio with gradle dependency compile `"com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.+"` . Now I am able to get notification only in lollipop devices. Why I didn't  get notification in Kitkat or lower level devices. I am able to get register Id for GCM in all devices. But not  getting notification in device other than lollipop. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Can you post your manifest? (and the code)

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you can provide your code. 
In addition, it is probably (I guess) that you do not perform PlayServices check on your KitKat device.